# What is the informal equivalent of いいえ

Tags: colloquial-language, register, informal

I was initially taught that いえ was the informal version of いいえ. Recently, I have read on several websites that いえ should only be used to refer to house/home 家. Is this true and if so, what is the negative equivalent of え?

Comment: いえ is *relatively* more informal than いいえ, but いえ is used mostly in formal and polite speech. It's probably much more common than いいえ, too.

Answer (score 10):

いえ is definitely used informally for いいえ, though it's not super casual. More casual options include いや, ううん, or 違う. That being said, you don't necessarily need a word that means 'no'; you can reply to 「フランスに行ったことある？」with just 「ないよ」

Comment: I would have thought 違う is *less* casual (though of course it's more casual than 違います); it's the sort of thing you say because a direct "no" isn't appropriate for the situation... ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry for the late reply, but 違う is actually an extremely direct way of saying 'no